React Native Expo не получает данные c помощью websocket
Я пытаюсь написать свой чат на react native expo  c помощью websocket.
В функции socket.onmessage в event.data почему-то пустой массив.
socket.onmessage = (event) => {
      console.log(event);

      messages.push({ text: event.data, isMyMsg: false });
      setMessages(messages);
    };

Так же я пробовал переделать с помощью Blob:
useEffect(() => {
    const socket = new WebSocket(WS_URL);
    socket.binaryType = "blob";

    socket.onopen = () => {
      console.log("Соединение установлено");
      setIsConnected(true);
      setWs(socket);
    };

    socket.onmessage = async (event) => {
      const blob = event.data;
      console.log(event);

      if (blob instanceof Blob) {
        const text = await blob.text(); // Преобразуем Blob в текст
        console.log("Получено сообщение:", text);

        messages.push({ text: text, isMyMsg: false });
        setMessages(messages);
      } else {
        console.error("Неизвестный формат сообщения:", blob);
      }
    };

    socket.onclose = () => {
      console.log("Соединение закрыто");
      setIsConnected(false);
    };

    socket.onerror = (error) => {
      console.error("Ошибка соединения:", error);
    };

    return () => {
      socket.close();
    };
  }, []);

Здесь код останавливается на строчке const text = await blob.text() и дальше не выполняется.
Я пробовал подключать клиент на обычном js к серверу и он нормально работал получал и отправлял сообщения. Скорее всего проблема в React Native expo, но я не понимаю как ее решить.
весь код:
chat_content.tsx
import { View, FlatList, Text } from "react-native";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import Message from "@/components/Message";
import FormField from "@/components/FormField";
import { useLocalSearchParams } from "expo-router/build/hooks";
import { IChatView } from "@/components/Chat";

export interface IMessage {
  isMyMsg: boolean;
  text: string;
}

const WS_URL = "myurl";

const ChatContent = () => {
  const data = useLocalSearchParams()["data"];
  const chatView: IChatView = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(data as string));

  const [messages, setMessages] = useState<Array<IMessage>>([]);
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const [ws, setWs] = useState<WebSocket | null>(null);
  const [isConnected, setIsConnected] = useState(false);

  const sendMessage = (msg: string) => {
    if (ws && ws.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN && msg !== "") {
      ws.send(msg);
      messages.push({ text: msg, isMyMsg: true });
      setMessages(messages);
      setValue("");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = new WebSocket(WS_URL);
socket.onopen = () => {
  console.log("Соединение установлено");
  setIsConnected(true);
  setWs(socket);
};

socket.onmessage = (event) => {
  console.log(event);

  messages.push({ text: event.data, isMyMsg: false });
  setMessages(messages);
};

socket.onclose = () => {
  console.log("Соединение закрыто");
  setIsConnected(false);
};

socket.onerror = (error) => {
  console.error("Ошибка соединения:", error);
};

return () => {
  socket.close();
};
  }, []);

return (
    <SafeAreaView className="h-full pb-2 px-2 flex-col justify-end">
      <View
        className="
        absolute
        w-[100vw]
        right-[-50%] 
        translate-x-[-4%]
        overflow-hidden
        top-1
        h-10
        z-10
      "
      >
        <Text className="font-semibold text-xl">{chatView.name}</Text>
      </View>
      <FlatList
        inverted={true}
        contentContainerStyle={{ flexDirection: "column-reverse" }}
        data={messages}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <Message isMyMsg={item.isMyMsg} text={item.text} />
        )}
      />
      <View>
        <FormField
          fieldStyles="bg-white"
          inputStyles="text-black font-semibold text-xl"
          titleStyle=""
          title="Message"
          value={value}
          handleChangeText={(e) => setValue(e)}
          sendMessage={() => sendMessage(value)}
        />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
export default ChatContent;

server.js
    const WebSocket = require("ws");
    
    const ws = new WebSocket("myurl");
    
    ws.on("open", function open() {
      console.log("Соединение установлено");
      ws.send("Тестовое сообщение");
      sendMessage();
    });
    
    ws.on("message", function incoming(data) {
      console.log(`Сообщение от сервера: ${data}`);
    });
    
    ws.on("close", function close() {
      console.log("Соединение закрыто");
    });
    
    ws.on("error", function error(err) {
      console.error("Ошибка:", err.message);
    });
    
    function sendMessage() {
      const readline = require("readline").createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout,
      });
    
      readline.on("line", (message) => {
        if (message === "/quit") {
          console.log("Выход...");
          ws.close();
          readline.close();
          return;
        }
    
        ws.send(message);
        readline.prompt();
      });
    }

Работающий client.js
const WebSocket = require("ws");

const ws = new WebSocket("myurl");

ws.on("open", function open() {
  console.log("Соединение установлено");
  ws.send("Тестовое сообщение");
  sendMessage();
});

ws.on("message", function incoming(data) {
  console.log(`Сообщение от сервера: ${data}`);
});

ws.on("close", function close() {
  console.log("Соединение закрыто");
});

ws.on("error", function error(err) {
  console.error("Ошибка:", err.message);
});

function sendMessage() {
  const readline = require("readline").createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });

  readline.on("line", (message) => {
    if (message === "/quit") {
      console.log("Выход...");
      ws.close();
      readline.close();
      return;
    }

    ws.send(message);
    readline.prompt();
  });
}

